# JSF 2: access selected value of selectOneMenu in a form BEFORE submit

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**VIEW**

```
<h:form id="main_form">
    <p:inputText id="title" required="true" label="Title" value="#{myBean.myLink.title}" immediate="true" />

    <p:selectOneMenu id="scope" required="true" label="Scope" value="#{myBean.myLink.scope}" immediate="true" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please choose" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.availableScopes}" id="selScope"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:inputText id="link" required="true" label="URL" value="#{myBean.myLink.link}" immediate="true">      
        <p:ajax event="blur" update="msgLink" listener="#{myBean.checkUrl}" />
    </p:inputText>

    ... msgLink and other (required) elements

    ... submit button
</h:form>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
@Component("myBean")
@Scope("session")
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private Link myLink;
    private Map<String, String> availableScopes;

    public MyBean() {
        this.availableScopes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.availableScopes.put("Intranet", "Intranet");
        this.availableScopes.put("Internet", "Internet");   
    }

    // setter/getters etc.

    public void checkUrl() {
        System.out.println(myLink.getTitle());  // works
        System.out.println(myLink.getScope());  // DOES NOT work
        System.out.println(myLink.getLink());   // works
    }

}
```

- I want to check the URL depending of the selected scope **before** submitting the form. But the called method can access the `inputText` values of the object. Not the value chosen in `selectOneMenu`.
- I have tried it with `getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("scope")` but the SessionMap is null at that time.

Any chance to access the selected value of the combo box?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<p:ajax>` (and `<f:ajax>`) inside an `UIInput` component executes/processes by default the **current** `UIInput` component (`@this`) only, not others.

If you want to execute/process all those `UIInput` components when the listener method is to be invoked, then you should specify that as such in `<p:ajax process>` (or `<f:ajax execute>`) attribute:

```
<p:inputText id="title" ... />

<p:selectOneMenu id="scope" ... >
    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputText id="link" ...>      
    <p:ajax process="title scope link" ... />
</p:inputText>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I wonder how all those `immediate="true"` attributes are useful in this context. Are you certain you need them?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try it now, although i am very much sure it work will :-) Regarding the `immediate="true"`: These are just remains of one of my tries ;-)

Comment: Just another question so i understand it correctly: In the above example not only the current `UIInput` component was processed but also the very first `inputText` component (id=title). The value was available in the listener method. Is this the normal behaviour? Is there a difference between `inputText` and `selectOneMenu` regarding their process behaviour?

Comment: Nope. Apparently you're looking at some initial value or there's in your actual code a `<p:ajax>` on the input component.

Comment: Yes, there is `<p:ajax>` in the input comonent. Sorry i overlooked that.